# Best way to reuse a large translation file within Node / Express

Tags: node.js, express, gettext

I'm new to Node but I figured I'd jump right in and start converting a PHP app into Node/Express. It's a bilingual app that uses `gettext` with PO/MO files. I found a Node module called `node-gettext`. I'd rather not convert the PO files into another format right now, so it seems this library is my only option.

So my concern is that right now, before every page render, I'm doing something like this:

```
exports.home_index = function(req, res)
{
    var gettext = require('node-gettext'),
        gt = new gettext();

    var fs = require('fs');
    gt.textdomain('de');
    var fileContents = fs.readFileSync('./locale/de.mo');
    gt.addTextdomain('de', fileContents);

    res.render(
        'home/index.ejs',
        { gt: gt }
    );
};
```

I'll also be using the translations in classes, so with how it's set up now I'd have to load the entire translation file again every time I want to translate something in another place.

The translation file is about 50k and I really don't like having to do file operations like this on every page load. In Node/Express, what would be the most efficient way to handle this (aside from a database)? Usually a user won't even be changing their language after the first time (if they're changing it from English).

---

**EDIT:**

Ok, I have no idea if this is a good approach, but it at least lets me reuse the translation file in other parts of the app without reloading it everywhere I need to get translated text.

In app.js:

```
var express         = require('express'),
    app             = express(),
    ...
    gettext         = require('node-gettext'),
    gt              = new gettext();
```

Then, also in app.js, I create the variable `app.locals.gt` to contain the gettext/translation object, and I include my middleware function:

```
app.locals.gt = gt;
app.use(locale());
```

In my middleware file I have this:

mod

```
module.exports = function locale()
{
    return function(req, res, next)
    {
        // do stuff here to populate lang variable
        var fs = require('fs');
        req.app.locals.gt.textdomain(lang);
        var fileContents = fs.readFileSync('./locales/' + lang + '.mo');
        req.app.locals.gt.addTextdomain(lang, fileContents);

        next();
    };
};
```

It doesn't seem like a good idea to assign the loaded translation file to `app`, since depending on the current request that file will be one of two languages. If I assigned the loaded translation file to `app` instead of a request variable, can that mix up users' languages?

Anyway, I know there's got to be a better way of doing this.

Comment: If you don't want to load it every time you have to have some kind of cache or global variable. You might look into some data caching libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option would be to do the following:

Add this in app.js:

```
var languageDomains = {};
```

Then modify your Middleware:

```
module.exports = function locale()
{
    return function(req, res, next)
    {
        // do stuff here to populate lang variable
        if ( !req.app.locals.languageDomains[lang] ) {
          var fs = require('fs');
          var fileContents = fs.readFileSync('./locales/' + lang + '.mo');
          req.app.locals.languageDomains[lang] = true;
          req.app.locals.gt.addTextdomain(lang, fileContents);
        }
        req.textdomain = req.app.locals.gt.textdomain(lang);
        next();
    };
};
```

By checking if the file has already been loaded you are preventing the action from happening multiple times, and the domain data will stay resident in the server's memory. The downside to the simplicity of this solution is that if you ever change the contents of your `.mo` files whilst the server is running, the changes wont be taken into account. However, this code could be extended to keep an eye on the `mtime` of the files, and reload accordingly, or make use of [`fs.watchFile`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener) — if required:

```
if ( !req.app.locals.languageDomains[lang] ) {
  var fs = require('fs'), filename = './locales/' + lang + '.mo';
  var fileContents = fs.readFileSync(filename);
  fs.watchFile(filename, function (curr, prev) {
    req.app.locals.gt.addTextdomain(lang, fs.readFileSync(filename));
  });
  req.app.locals.languageDomains[lang] = true;
  req.app.locals.gt.addTextdomain(lang, fileContents);
}
```

> **Warning:** It should also be noted that using sync versions of functions outside of server initialisation is not a good idea because it can freeze the thread. You'd be better off changing your sync loading to the async equivalent.

After the above changes, rather than passing `gt` to your template, you should be able to use `req.textdomain` instead. It seems that the [gettext](https://github.com/andris9/node-gettext/tree/e193c67fdee439ab9710441ffd9dd96d027317b9) library supports a number of requests directly on each domain object, which means you hopefully don't need to refer to the global `gt` object on a per request basis (which will be changing it's default domain on each request):

Each domain supports:

1. getTranslation
2. getComment
3. setComment
4. setTranslation
5. deleteTranslation
6. compilePO
7. compileMO

Taken from here:

https://github.com/andris9/node-gettext/blob/e193c67fdee439ab9710441ffd9dd96d027317b9/lib/domain.js

#### update

A little bit of further clarity.

Once the server has loaded the file into memory the first time, it should remain there for all subsequent connections it receives (for any visitor/request) because it is stored globally and wont be garbage collected — unless you remove all references to the data, which would mean `gettext` would need to have some kind of unload/forget domain method.

Node is different to PHP in that its environment is shared and wraps its own HTTP server (if you are using something like Express), which means it is very easy to remember data globally as it has a constant environment that all the code is executed within. PHP is always executed after the HTTP server has received and dealt with the request (e.g. Apache). Each PHP response is then executed in its own separate run-time, which means you have to rely on databases, sessions and cache stores to share even simple information and most resources.

#### further optimisations

Obviously with the above you are constantly running translations on each page load. Which means the `gettext` library will still be using the translation data resident in memory, which will take up processing time. To get around this, it would be best to make sure your URLs have something that makes them unique for each different language i.e. `my-page/en/` or `my.page.fr` or even `jp.domain.co.uk/my-page` and then enable some kind of full page caching using something like `memcached` or [express-view-cache](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-view-cache). However, once you start caching pages you need to make certain there aren't any regions that are user specific, if so, you need to start implement more complicated systems that are sensitive to these areas.

> **Remember:** The golden rule of optimisation, don't do so before you need to... basically meaning I wouldn't worry about page caching until you know it's going to be an issue, but it is always worth bearing in mind what your options are, as it should shape your code design.

#### update 2

Just to illustrate a bit further on the behaviour of a server running in JavaScript, and how the global behaviour is not just a property of `req.app`, but in fact any object that is further up the scope chain.

So, as an example, instead of adding `var languageDomains = {};` to your app.js, you could instantiate it further up the scope of wherever your middleware is placed. It's best to keep your global entities in one place however, so app.js is the better place, but this is just for illustration.

```
var languageDomains = {};

module.exports = function locale()
{
   /// you can still access languageDomains here, and it will behave 
   /// globally for the entire server.
   languageDomains[lang]
}
```

So basically, where-as with PHP, the entire code-base is re-executed on each request — so the `languageDomains` would be instantiated a-new each time — in Node the only part of the code to be re-executed is the code within `locale()` (because it is triggered as part of a new request). This function will still have a reference to the already existing and defined `languageDomains` via the scope chain. Because `languageDomains` is never reset (on a per request basis) it will behave globally.

#### Concurrent users

Node.js is single threaded. This means that in order for it to be concurrent i.e. handle multiple requests at the "same" time, you have to code your app in such a way that each little part can be executed very quickly and then slip into a waiting state, whilst another part of another request is dealt with.

This is the reason for the asynchronous and callback nature of Node, and the reason to avoid Sync calls whilst your app is running. Any one Sync request could halt or freeze execution of the thread and delay handling for all other requests. The reason why I state this is to give you a better idea of how multiple users might interact with your code (and global objects).

Basically once a request is being dealt with by your server, it is it's only focus, until that particular execution cycle ends i.e. your request handler stops calling other code that needs to run synchronously. Once that happens the next queued item is dealt with (a callback or something), this could be part of another request, or it could be the next part in the current request.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, pebbl. With this method, the translation file will still need to be read/loaded on every page load, correct? But it will only need to load once, right?

Comment: @Gavin ~ Check the update in my answer, hopefully it should clarify in a bit more detail.

Comment: Thanks! That really helps me get my head around this and better understand Node. So are all `req.app.*` variables available to all users/connections no matter which user set the variable? For example if inside of some function I had an `if (user.id == 20) { req.app.local.myvar = 'hello!' }` and the user with id=20 visited the site, would every user from that point on (until the server is restarted) have access to this variable, regardless of their user id?

Comment: @Gavin ~ No problem! Yes that's pretty much it, however it wont just be `req.app` any variable/object that is kept alive will have the same behaviour. So anything in the global scope, or at least outside of any function that is called on a per request basis. If you haven't read up on JavaScript scope I suggest you do so as it behaves quite differently to PHP. Check my update in my answer for a bit more information.